# RateLimiter [resilience4j] - 429 Too Many Requests (exceeded limit) and RequestNotPermitted

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jmeter, rate-limiting, resilience4j

### My implementation

**I use**:

- spring-boot `2.7.2`
- resilience4j `1.7.0` (`resilience4j-spring-boot2` - with `aop`)
- spring-cloud-starter-openfeign

**Client looks like this**:

```
@FeignClient(value = "userClient", url = "${user.api.url:localhost}", path = "/${user.api.version:v1.0}", configuration = UserApiClientConfiguration.class)
public interface UserClient {

    @GetMapping(value = "/users", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @RateLimiter(name = "user-throttling")
    List<JsonNode> getUsers();
}
```

In `UserApiClientConfiguration` I have some oauth2 beans, that basically narrow down to calling `OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager#authorize` in feign request interceptor to get `access_token` (either from memory, or by sending request to the auth. server).

**Config for ratelimiter looks like this** (as the remote users api has throttling with max 6 requests per 1 second)

```
resilience4j:
  ratelimiter:
    instances:
      user-throttling:
        limitForPeriod: 6
        limitRefreshPeriod: 1s
        timeoutDuration: 0
```

**My tests seems to be working fine**:

```
@Test
void rateLimiterShouldAllowForCalls() {
  // given
  ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);

  // when
  List<Future<List<JsonNode>>> requests = IntStream.range(0, 6).boxed()
          .map(e -> executorService.submit(() -> userClient.getUsers()))
          .toList();

  // then
  assertDoesNotThrow(() -> {
      for (Future<List<JsonNode>> request : requests) {
          request.get();
      }
  });
}

@Test
void rateLimiterShouldNotAllowFurtherCalls() {
  // given
  ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(7);

  // when
  List<Future<List<JsonNode>>> requests = IntStream.range(0, 7).boxed()
          .map(e -> executorService.submit(() -> userClient.getUsers()))
          .toList();

  // then
  assertThrows(ExecutionException.class, () -> {
      for (Future<?> request : requests) {
          request.get();
      }
  }, "io.github.resilience4j.ratelimiter.RequestNotPermitted: RateLimiter 'user-throttling' does not permit further calls");
}
```

---

### **The problem**:

In the application, I created an endpoint, that will call `userClient.getUsers()`. I use it in `JMeter`.

### 1

- `JMeter` with following config:

  - Number of threads (Users): `8`
  - Ramp-up period (seconds): `0`
  - Loop count: `1`

gives me expected:

```
io.github.resilience4j.ratelimiter.RequestNotPermitted: RateLimiter 'user-throttling' does not permit further calls"
```

### 2

But sometimes, f.e. when:

- I use `JMeter` with the following config:

  - Number of threads (Users): `15`
  - Ramp-up period (seconds): `1`
  - Loop count: `1`

I get **both**:

```
io.github.resilience4j.ratelimiter.RequestNotPermitted: RateLimiter 'user-throttling' does not permit further calls"
```

and

```
DEBUG i.g.r.r.configure.RateLimiterAspect      : Created or retrieved rate limiter 'user-throttling' with period: 'PT1S'; limit for period: '6'; timeout: 'PT2S'; method: 'package.UserClient#getUsers'
ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.FeignException$TooManyRequests: [429 Too Many Requests] during [GET] to [https://api.users.test/v1.0/users] [UserClient#getUsers()]: []] with root cause

feign.FeignException$TooManyRequests: [429 Too Many Requests] during [GET] to [https://api.users.test/v1.0/users] [UserClient#getUsers()]: []
    at feign.FeignException.clientErrorStatus(FeignException.java:231) ~[feign-core-11.10.jar:na]
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:194) ~[feign-core-11.10.jar:na]
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:185) ~[feign-core-11.10.jar:na]
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:92) ~[feign-core-11.10.jar:na]
    at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.handleResponse(AsyncResponseHandler.java:98) ~[feign-core-11.10.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:141) ~[feign-core-11.10.jar:na]
```

---

### **Question**

1. **Is my RateLimiter not configured properly that I get both: `io.github.resilience4j.ratelimiter.RequestNotPermitted` and `feign.FeignException$TooManyRequests: [429 Too Many Requests]` (response from remote API) in `2nd` case of my `JMeter` configuration?**
2. Why RateLimiter seems to be working fine only to certain level and then it allows for more than `6`req/`1`sek that I'm being stopped by the remote API rather than by me own RateLimiter implementation?